# Accessing a string inside a struct inside an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056111/converting-a-string-back-to-an-array-in-swift but below is generically what I'm trying to do.  results in no match:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

struct myStruct {
    var name: String? = ""
}

let myArray: [myStruct] = [myStruct(name: "Gary")]

var userName = "Gary"

let instanceofStruct = myStruct()

if userName == instanceofStruct.name {
    println("match")
}
else {
    println("no match")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use '==' instead of '===' to compare `Strings`.

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82):

> Note that “identical to” (represented by three equals signs, or ===)
>   does not mean the same thing as “equal to” (represented by two equals
>   signs, or ==):
>
> • “Identical to” means that two constants or variables of class type
>   refer to exactly the same class instance.
>
> • “Equal to” means that two instances are considered “equal” or
>   “equivalent” in value, for some appropriate meaning of “equal”, as
>   defined by the type’s designer.

Note that `String` is a `Struct`, which is a **value type**, not a class.

---

#### After the questions was updated:

```
var userName = "Gary"

let instanceofStruct = myStruct() // instanceofStruct.name is "" here

if userName == instanceofStruct.name { // "Gary" != ""
    println("match")
}
else {
    println("no match")
}
```

What you probably want to do is:

```
let myArray: [myStruct] = [myStruct(name: "Gary")]

var userName = "Gary"

var structireWithNameGary: myStruct? = nil
for structure in myArray {
    if userName == structure.name {
        println("match")
        structireWithNameGary = structure
        break
    }
}

if structireWithNameGary != nil {
    println("found a stucture with name Gary in myArray")
} else {
    println("couldn't find a stucture with name Gary in myArray")
}
```

Comment: but I don't know which array is being called, it's user's choice, which is why I need to match the variable (string) chosen with it's corresponding struct in my array.

Comment: Sorry man, but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated my answer, but if it doesn't help, you should try to articulate your goals better.

Comment: amazing man...I thought maybe a for in loop might be necessary but wasn't sure how to structure it.  Thanks!!

Comment: Np. I strongly suggest you read the [Swfit Book](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11). It may take some of your time, but, speaking from experience, it will make you a much better Swift programmer.